# Proving lower sum inequality

Tags: integration, solution-verification

For bounded function $f$ and $g$ on $[a,b]$, $h = f + g$
I have proved that $\underline{\int_a^b}(f) \; + \; \underline{\int_a^b}(g) \; \leq \;  \underline{\int_a^b}(h)$ holds. 
But is it always true that $\underline{\int_a^b}(f) \; + \; \underline{\int_a^b}(g) \; = \;  \underline{\int_a^b}(h)$?
I try to prove that $\underline{\int_a^b}(f) \; + \; \underline{\int_a^b}(g) \; \geq \;  \underline{\int_a^b}(h)$ also holds so maybe I can reach the conclusion.
It seems like the statement is true but I had trouble proving it.

Comment: Why is the question body deleted now?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter statement is false. Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]\\  1, &x \in (\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1] \end{cases}$$ and $g(x) = 1-f(x)$. Then the lower sum of both $f$ and $g$ are $0$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but the lower sum of $f+g=1$ is $1$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks very much!